# Mostrar anuncios no personalizables - AdMob

Tags: android, admob

hace unos días he implementado el nuevo sistema de **AdMob 'TCF v2.0'** para respetar **GDPR**, todo parecia estar bien implementado, al iniciar la aplicación al usuario le sale un dialogo preguntando si quiere dar o no consentimiento para tener anuncios personalizados.

El problema viene cuando solo un día después al entrar en mi AdMob tengo un mensaje con el siguiente error:

> Errores detectados relativos al TCF v2.0 de la IAB Hemos detectado
> problemas con su cadena sobre el Marco de Transparencia y
> Consentimiento de la IAB en uno o varios de sus sitios web o
> aplicaciones. Es posible que estos errores afecten a su capacidad para
> mostrar anuncios a usuarios europeos. Puede ver un informe detallado
> en la página Consentimiento de usuarios de la UE.

Descargando el informe lo único que dice es que el error es **'1.1'**, después de estar investigando por foros y demás, veo que el problema está cuando el usuario le da a no consentir anuncios personalizados, cuando hacen eso la aplicación deja de mostrar anuncios, ya sean personalizados o no personalizados.

No sé que debo hacer o si es un error de AdMob. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    public class Pruebas extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
    private ConsentForm consentForm;
    ConsentRequestParameters params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pruebas);

        params = new ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().build();
        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);

        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                            loadForm();
                        } else
                            mostarPublicidad();
                    }
                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError onConsentInfoUpdateFailure) {
                        mostarPublicidad();
                    }
                });
    }

    public void loadForm() {
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        Pruebas.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {

                            consentForm.show(
                                    Pruebas.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });

                        } else {
                            mostarPublicidad();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        mostarPublicidad();
                        /// Handle Error.
                        //   Log.e("error", "error version:  " + t.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void mostarPublicidad() {
        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Debiste recibir un email donde especifica aceptar un acuerdo relacionadas a las políticas de uso de anuncios.

"al iniciar la aplicación al usuario le sale un dialogo preguntando si quiere dar o no consentimiento para tener anuncios personalizados." El usuario debe aceptar o rechazar.

El error que obtienes se especifica aquí:

[AdMob & AdSense program policies
Troubleshooting TCF v2.0 implementation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9999955?hl=en)

El error 1.1 indica:

Descripción:
**Google, como proveedor, no está autorizado bajo consentimiento o interés legítimo.**

Acción a tomar:
**Confirme si el usuario rechazó intencionalmente a Google como proveedor, si se han producido errores de implementación de CMP o si existen restricciones de editor.**

Desgraciadamente ahora si el usuario no acepta este tipo de anuncios, simplemente no se le van a mostrar y no van a ser monetizados.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he leído el error, pero sigo sin saber que tengo que hacer. Debo cambiar algo en mi adMob? Se supone que si no aceptan, simplemente le deberían salir anuncios no personalizados, no?

Comment: Depende del usuario aceptar o no, si no acepta no se mostrarían, eso no lo podrías controlar.

Comment: según la documentación de Google eso no es así, el dialog es para que decidas si quieres anuncios personalizados o no, no es una opción para desactivar cualquier tipo de anuncio